# Properties of an apparently new triangle centre with trilinear coordinates $\frac1{\sqrt{a\cos A}}:\frac1{\sqrt{b\cos B}}:\frac1{\sqrt{c\cos C}}$

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

[This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3927906/357390) asked:

> In an acute triangle $ABC$ let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be the intersections of the altitude from $A$ and the circle with diameter $BC$, with $A_1$ closer to $A$. $B_1$, $B_2$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are defined cyclically. $A'$ is the intersection of $B_1C_2$ and $B_2C_1$; $B'$ and $C'$ are defined cyclically. Show that $AA'$, $BB'$ and $CC'$ concur at a point $X$.

[image]

[I have answered that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3928468/357390), showing that the trilinear coordinates of $X$ are
$$X=\frac1{a\sqrt{b^2+c^2-a^2}}:\frac1{b\sqrt{c^2+a^2-b^2}}:\frac1{c\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{a\cos A}}:\frac1{\sqrt{b\cos B}}:\frac1{\sqrt{c\cos C}}$$
where $A,B,C,a,b,c$ have their usual meaning (the angles and sides of the underlying triangle).

However, I could not find this centre in Kimberling's [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centres](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html), especially since the centre is a real point only for non-obtuse triangles whereas the reference triangles used for the [numeric lookup tables](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/Search_6_9_13.html) are obtuse. (Even the special instruction that the argument of $x$ be taken if it is a complex number doesn't help.)

Before I submit a request to add this centre to the ETC: **is it already in there?** If not, **what properties does this centre have** (any lines/curves it is on, conjugates, etc.)?

From the provided trilinear coordinates above it is easy to see that $X$ is the "trilinear square root" of $X_{92}$ (the square root of $x:y:z$ is $\sqrt x:\sqrt y:\sqrt z$) and the "barycentric square root" of the orthocentre $X_4$, but searching for those terms in the ETC yielded no results either.

Comment: The instructions for looking up an imaginary trilinear are to use its modulus.  But in most cases the imaginary will be the square root of a negative real and therefore the modulus will be $\pm \pi/2$.  So is that a typo?

Comment: @brainjam I figured out what to do for complex trilinears using $X_{5374}$. Compute the normalised trilinear $kx$ as usual. _If_ this is a complex number, take $\arg kx$ and use that as the search key. In this case, however, the centre I define here has key around $0.78$, and it's not in the $6,9,13$ table, so it must really be a new centre.